# Set profile Active/Inactive using ASP.NET Profiles

Tags: asp.net, profile

Using the built-in ASP.NET Web Profiles, how do I create a user account that is Inactive (i.e., Active == false) and then later (for example, after sending the user an activation link in an e-mail) set their profile to Active?

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `IsApproved` property of the `MembershipUser`class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx).

If `IsApproved` is set to false, validation for the user will fail even if the the username and password are correct.